# Derivatives of a Linear and Cubic Bézier curve

Tags: derivatives, bezier-curve

Thanks to the answer here:

[how to calculate the value of "t" for the highest point in a quadratic bezier curve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005127/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-t-for-the-highest-point-in-a-quadratic-bezier-cu)

I know that the derivative of the quadratic bézier curve of

> $P(t) = P_0(1−t)^2 + P_12t(1−t) + P_2t^2$

is

> $P′(t) = −2(P_0 − P_1) + 2t_∗(P_0 − P_1) + 2t_∗(P_2 − P_1)$

But I'm afraid I don't understand how that's derived.

I know Wikipedia lists the equation for a bézier derivative as

> $B′(t) = n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_{i, n-1} (t)(P_{i+1} - P_i)$

But I frankly understand that even less. Just that it's series notation?

So then the derivative of the linear curve

> $P(t) = (1-t)P_0 + tP_1$

would be?

> $P′(t) = P_1 − P_0$

*(Thanks to bubba)*

And what would be the derivative of the cubic curve?

> $P(t) = P_0(1-t)^3 + P_13t(1-t)^2 + P_23t^2(1-t) + P_3t^3$

Comment: The formatting makes the question hard to read (I fixed some of it), and I suspect that there are several typos.

Comment: And your link to the other answer is broken.

Comment: The derivatives are just calculated the way you would in Calculus 101. You can pretend the points are just numbers. So the answer for the linear case is $P’(t)= P_1 - P_0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve#Cubic_Bézier_curves

Comment: @bubba: The link to another Question (and its answer) was not so much broken as not proper MarkDown.  So I fixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

You just treat the points as numerical constants, and differentiate the way they teach you in calculus classes. So, for the quadratic curve, we have
$$
P(t) = P_0\,(1-t)^2 + P_1\,2t(1-t) + P_2\,t^2
$$
We expand the “$t$” terms to get
$$
P(t) = P_0\,(1-2t+t^2)+P_1\,(2t - 2t^2) + P_2\,t^2
$$
Then we differentiate, which gives
\begin{align*}
P’(t) &= P_0\,(-2+2t)+P_1\,(2 - 4t) + P_2\,(2t). \\
&=2\big\{ P_0\,(t-1)+P_1\,(1-2t) + P_2\,(t) \big\} \\
&=2\big\{ P_0\,(t-1)+P_1\,(1-t) - P_1\,(t) + P_2\,(t) \big\} \\
&= 2\big\{ (P_1 - P_0)\,(1-t) + (P_2 - P_1)\,(t) \big\}
\end{align*}
This is slightly different from the formula you quoted, but it’s nicer because it shows that the derivative of a quadratic (degree 2) Bézier curve is actually a linear (degree 1) Bézier curve.

By similar reasoning, you can show that the derivative of the cubic curve is
$$
3\big\{ (1-t)^2(P_1 - P_0) + 2t(1-t)(P_2 - P_1) + t^2 (P_3- P_2)\big\}
$$
So again we can see that the derivative of a cubic Bézier curve is a quadratic Bézier curve.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow how you got from step 2 to step 3 in your differentiation of the quadratic. Can you add the intermediate steps?

Comment: I added a step. The key is that $1-2t = (1-t)-t$.